# Drop boolean rows from dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I quickly drop rows where A, B and C are all false?
I tried:

```
df3 = df[~(~(df['A'])& ~(df['B']) & ~(df['C']) )]
df3
   com     A        B           C
0  as     TRUE    FALSE       FALSE
1  da     TRUE    FALSE       FALSE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wait a mins `any`

```
df[df[['A','B','C']].any(1)]
```

Comment: This is the easiest built-in way..!!

Comment: 100% agree, I completely over-thought this one 

Answer (score 5):

> drop rows where A, B and C are are all false

With [`df.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) across `axis=1` along with comparison if `sum` in the row for these coumns is not equal to 0 , using [`df.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html)

```
out = df[df[['A','B','C']].sum(1).ne(0)].copy()
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind explaining this sorry? I didn't quite follow.

Comment: @asd when you take sum of each row for columns `A,B,C` , if there is any `True` value, it will return 1 or more , hence I check if the sum is not equal to zero (which means all columns for a row is `False`)

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, what's wrong with the code I wrote? Am I misunderstanding some syntax or?

Comment: @asd what you do is `False&False&False` (which is `False`) ( assuming all the columns in the row is  False) , then you invert it (`~`) which will always return `True` so for rows having all `False` values it still returns `True` and hence doesnot drop it

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using `all` along axis 1. The 2nd `~` operator directly - directly before `df`, reversed all `False` to `True`. `all` returns `True` if all column values are `True`, then using `~` again to reverse this to index rows that are actually all `False`:

```
df3 = df[~(~df[['A', 'B', 'C']]).all(1)]
```